# creating an TSQL Makro for daily usage

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to create a `Makro` for myself that Converts a Star into a list of Columns.

My Question here is: Is there any way to Access the Tool tip that my SQL Server 2014 gives me when I hover over the said Star.

My intention here ist that if i have a Statement like

> Select * from #TempTab   
>           join Tab1 on Temp_ID=Tab_ID 
>           join Tab2 on Tab1_ID = Tab2_Tab1_ID 
>   ...

the only thing i have to do is pressing a 'Makro' and my Star gets replaced by the current list of Columns

Comment: There are various SSMS addins that do wildcard column list expansion. You would need to use one of those or write your own. Or use SSDT which has it built in.

Answer (score 0):

Use SSMS built in option.

Right click your table name in the object explorer then select top 1000 rows.
It gives you all columns with top 1000 records.